# Content Management Document Library - How to get Approval Status column value using SPMetal LINQ

Tags: spmetal

I am trying to pull data from  Content Management Document library , Äpproval Status  is not a actual document library column. It was enabled through Content Management Feature....

How to i access Approval Status Value from my Event Receiver (VS2010) using SPMetal?

Answer (score 1):

spmetal will not generate the _ModerationStatus  field  because the field is not belong to the document contenttype.

you can simply write a partial class to add a ModerationStatus property manually

```
public partial class YOUR_DOCUMENT_CLASS 
{
    private System.Nullable<SPModerationStatus> _ModerationStatus;
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ColumnAttribute(Name = "_ModerationStatus", Storage = "_ModerationStatus", FieldType = "Choice")]
    public System.Nullable<SPModerationStatus> ModerationStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ModerationStatus;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((value != this._ModerationStatus))
            {
                this.OnPropertyChanging("ModerationStatus", this._ModerationStatus);
                this._ModerationStatus= value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("ModerationStatus");
            }
        }
    }
}

public enum SPModerationStatus: int {

    None = 0,

    Invalid = 1,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="0")]
    Approved = 2,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="1")]
    Rejected = 4,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="2")]
    Pending = 8,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="3")]
    Draft = 16,

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute(Value="4")]
    Scheduled = 32,
}
```

---

this code is write just now and then paste here, without any test, but i think it will works :), i have write some similar code in my project to get the author info, and works.

good luck

Comment: Hi Eric,thanks for the response. I'm always getting Invalid eventhough my Approval Status is Draft. Could you please guide me?

Comment: Sorry Jaffar, there's some mistake, the Value property of Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.ChoiceAttribute should be set to the _ModerationStatus field value of SPListItem, (file.Item["_ModerationStatus"]), after check the real data, i changed the SPModerationStatus in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the value out using a Parameter file for SPMetal like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Web xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SharePoint/2009/spmetal">
  <List Name="Images">
     <ContentType Name="Image" Class="ImageWithStatus">
       <Column Name="_ModerationStatus" Member="ModerationStatus" />
     </ContentType>
  </List>
  <ExcludeOtherLists />
</Web>
```

Run SPMetal like this:

> SPMetal /web:http://sp2010 /parameters:param.xml /code:test.cs